# Using useState with an if conditional inside of setInterval isn't working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, setinterval

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  let progressTimer;

  function handleTime() {
    if (progress <= 100) {
      console.log("Progress: " + progress);
      setProgress((prevState) => (prevState += 10));
    } else {
      console.log("greater");
      clearInterval(progressTimer);
    }
  }

  function handlePlay() {
    console.log("Timer start");
    progressTimer = setInterval(handleTime, 1000);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handlePlay();
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {progress}
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-lake-7orf2?file=/src/App.js)

**Desired outcome:** Go to 100, counting by 10 every 1 second. Once you reach over 100, turn off the timer.

**Actual outcome:** It just keeps going up and up, faster than 10 every 1 second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Issues

1. The `useEffect` to start an interval has no dependency array so a new interval was started each time the component rendered. This is what led to the bigger and bigger jumps.
2. The `progressTimer` is redeclared each render cycle so there's no way to clear it.
3. The check of the `progress` state is closed over in callback scope when passed to the `setInterval` callback. You're only ever looking at the initial state value. In other words, it's a stale enclosure.
4. Using `prevState => (prevState += 10)` in the functional state update actually mutates the previous state. All state mutations should be avoided.

## A Solution

1. Add a dependency array to the `useEffect` so it runs once on component mount. Move the `handlePlay` logic into the effect callback so there are no external dependencies when mounting. Don't forget to return a cleanup function to clear any running intervals when the component unmounts.
2. Store the `progressTimer` as a React ref so it's a stable reference.
3. Unmix the state update with the side-effect of clearing the timer. Use a second `useEffect` hook to check when the current `progress` value reaches 100.
4. In the state updater just return the previous state plus 10, `prevState => prevState + 10` as the next state value.

Code

```
function App() {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  const progressTimer = useRef();

  function handleTime() {
    setProgress((prevState) => prevState + 10);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Progress: " + progress);
    if (progress >= 100) clearInterval(progressTimer.current);
  }, [progress]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Timer start");
    progressTimer.current = setInterval(handleTime, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(progressTimer.current);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {progress}
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit using-usestate-with-an-if-conditional-inside-of-setinterval-isnt-working (forked)]

Comment: A very great solution @Drew , May I know why is `useRef()` used, if not used why the progress jumps and moves certainly fast than usually, what does `useRef()` have to do with this behaviour

Comment: @AgniGari The React ref is only used to hold a *reference* to an interval timer such that is can be mutated/read at anytime during the React component lifecycle, and is a stable reference render cycle to cycle. It hasn't much of anything to do with the actual running of the interval and associated callback, the `useEffect` hook callbacks manage that. Hopefully I've understood your question correctly.

Comment: I understood that, but I am puzzled because of the undefined behaviour of the time (progress) , when i use normal variable instead of useRef one , and when i dont clearInterval in the return of useEffect function. I am reffering to https://stackoverflow.com/a/75926385/13431819. The first two points i am not getting conviced, feel free to edit the post to add more value. That would be of great help

Comment: @AgniGari Can you clarify what exactly you mean by "normal variable" in your comment? I think what you are asking about is "oddness" that comes with storing/updating a value in state that doesn't really belong there, triggering additional rerenders, and not clearing old timers in the cleanup function which would leave more than 1 timer active at-a-time which leads to the callback being called more often than is intended, e.g. why the OPs were seeing the state "skip" values unexpectedly.

Comment: by "normal variable" I mean using `let currentTimer = 0;` instead of `const currentTimer = useRef();` I can see some weird jumps , same goes with while using `useRef()` variable but not using `return () => clearInterval(currentTimer.current);` in `useEffect(()=>{},[])` referring https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71172632/react-setinterval-and-usestate/75926385#75926385

Comment: @AgniGari I see. Well, there's not much difference between using a React ref and a locally global variable with regards to the component running. The difference would be apparent when you tried to render more than one instance of the component. The version using a React ref each instance gets their own timer ref, the version using a locally global variable all instances will use the same variable reference, so they will continually clobber the reference.

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` with React, when called on the first render, will result in the interval callback having a stale closure of the stateful variable(s) after the first render.

I'd use `setTimeout` instead, so that whenever the callback runs, it'll have scope of the most up-to-date state.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  function handleTime() {
    if (progress <= 100) {
      console.log("Progress: " + progress);
      setProgress((prevState) => (prevState += 10));
    } else {
      console.log("greater");
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const timerId = setTimeout(handleTime, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timerId);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {progress}
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```