# React setInterval and useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 question. First, why this code does not work. Second, why this code slow when it comes 2^n -1 for example 1-3-7-15

```
let time = 0
function App() {
  const [mytime, setMytime] = useState(time)
  setInterval(() => {
    time += 1
    setMytime(time)
  }, 1000)
  return <div> {mytime} </div>
```

Answer (score 13):

#### Issue

The `setInterval` gets called each time when `mytime` changes for rerendering (when you call the `setMytime`). And the number of `setInterval` calls grows exponentially. This would lead to a memory leak as well.

#### Solution

You should run it only once. You should use `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency array.

Try like this.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [mytime, setMytime] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // create a interval and get the id
    const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setMytime((prevTime) => prevTime + 1);
    }, 1000);
    // clear out the interval using the id when unmounting the component
    return () => clearInterval(myInterval);
  }, []);

  return <div> {mytime} </div>;
}

export default App;
```

[image: Edit competent-night-ufndlc]

Comment: To add some flavor to this correct answer, you also want to keep React component functions pure. By coupling your UI to a variable outside of the function you are changing a variable that existed before the function. The forthcoming React docs do a good job explaining why this is an anti-pattern and slowing down your app https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/keeping-components-pure#side-effects-unintended-consequences

Answer (score 4):

To extend @Amila's answer,

###### What if you want to `start`, `stop`, `reset` timer using `functions` ?

1. Make sure you use `useRef()`, because `useState()` will cause render.
2. Make sure you unmount the interval in the `useState()` as it will cause skipping of timer.

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
        return () => clearInterval(currentTimer.current);
    }, []);
   ```

Use the following code:

```
    const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
    const currentTimer = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        return () => clearInterval(currentTimer.current);
    }, []);
    const startTimer = () => {
        currentTimer.current = setInterval(() => {
            setTime((prev) => prev + 1);
            console.log(time);
        }, 1000);
    };
    const stopTimer = () => {
        clearInterval(currentTimer.current);
    };
    const resetTimer = () => {
        clearInterval(currentTimer.current);
        setTime(0);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <div>{time}</div>
            <button onClick={startTimer}>Start</button>
            <button onClick={stopTimer}>Stop</button>
            <button onClick={resetTimer}>Reset</button>
        </div>
    );
```