# How to show the final state from UseState in my CookieClicker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, render

i am a beginner with react and im working on a little clickergame.
My problem is, that i want to use useState to automaticly increase the number (with setInterval) but i also want to increase the number with click on the button. The shown percentages are wild hopping because he shows me an early state and a later state at the same time.

```
function App() {
  const [findWorkCount, setfindWorkCount] = useState(0);

  setInterval(findWorkRunner, '500');

  function findWorkRunner() {
    setfindWorkCount(findWorkCount + 1);

    if (findWorkCount >= 101) {
      setfindWorkCount(0);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setfindWorkCount(findWorkCount + 11);
        }}
      >
        Find Job
      </button>
      <div className="bar">
        <div className="fillwork" style={{ width: `${findWorkCount}%` }}>
          <div className="counter">{findWorkCount}%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React setInterval and useState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71172632/react-setinterval-and-usestate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the issue by using the callback form of setfindWorkCount in the setInterval to ensure the state update happens after the render:

```
function App() {
  const [findWorkCount, setfindWorkCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setfindWorkCount(c => c + 1);
  
      if (findWorkCount >= 101) {
        setfindWorkCount(0);
      }
    }, 500);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setfindWorkCount(c => c + 11);
        }}
      >
        Find Job
      </button>
      <div className="bar">
        <div className="fillwork" style={{ width: `${findWorkCount}%` }}>
          <div className="counter">{findWorkCount}%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use an interval in a function component you need to wrap in a `useEffect` block to ensure that it doesn't create an interval on each render. Since `findWorkRunner` is a dependency of the `useEffect`, you need to wrap it in `useCallback`. You should also use `findWorkRunner` for the button as well, so the same logic would apply to the button, and the interval updates.

Finally, use a [function to update](https://findWorkRunner) the state, because the updated state is computed using the previous state:

```
setfindWorkCount(count => 
  count + inc >= 101 ? 0 : count + inc
);
```

**Example:**

```js
const { useState, useCallback, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [findWorkCount, setfindWorkCount] = useState(0);

  const findWorkRunner = useCallback((inc = 1) => {
    setfindWorkCount(count => 
      count + inc >= 101 ? 0 : count + inc
    );
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(findWorkRunner, '500');
    
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [findWorkRunner]);
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          findWorkRunner(11);
        }}
      >
        Find Job
      </button>
      <div className="bar">
        <div className="fillwork" style={{ width: `${findWorkCount}%` }}>
          <div className="counter">{findWorkCount}%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up a `setTimeout` inside `useEffect` instead.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const id = setTimeout(() => {
    setfindWorkCount(findWorkCount + 1);
    if (findWorkCount >= 100) setfindWorkCount(0);
  }, 500);
  return () => clearTimeout(id);
}, [findWorkCount]);
```

Comment: what are the advantages to setInterval?